# KendoUI PopUP window has previous data

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

KendoUI popup window has previous data in it. I have a Add button and select an item in the data grid. After I select an item in the data grid to edit it if I close the KendoUI window and then click the Add button it still keeps some old values from edit like in dropdown values. How do I solve this?

Comment: Show us your code. You can also create a dojo or jsfiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Figured it out. Have to made a variable with the selected data. Then this selected variable has to be made blank just before the popup comesup.